# Design Patterns - Why the need for interfaces?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interfaces

OK. I am learning design patterns. Every time I see someone code an example of a design pattern they use interfaces. Here is an example:

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/06/18/the-facade-pattern-in-net.aspx?Page=1

Can someone explain to me why was the interfaces needed in this example to demonstrate the facade pattern? The program work if you pass in the classes to the facade instead of the interface. If I don't have interfaces does that mean

Comment: Did you read the intro in that article; it explains *exactly* why interfaces are important, and what their purpose is.  Specifically, "In this way, the end user only has to know the details of the Facade interface."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding interfaces](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163459/understanding-interfaces)

Comment: @Servy: the intro explains a facade as a higher level interface to lower level interfaces - but that is in no way an explanation why interfaces are needed at all.

Comment: You might want to read a something about [Abstract Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

Comment: It's just an example. Imagine that the subsystem interfaces are WCF service contract interfaces that someone else has provided to you. You have no access to the real implementation; all you have is the interface. Could it have been made to work without thesubsystem interfaces? Yes, but it would be less like a real world situation in which you would need to use the facade pattern.

Comment: @missingno: In languages like Java and C#, *classes* are used to define ADTs. Interfaces are used to define *objects*, not ADTs.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Interfaces define the specification for the ADT (the A part) and the classes specify different implementations. In a way, things would be simpler if the type of variables were always an interface and classes were used only for the constructors. In Java you can use class names as types (`MyClass x = new MyClass()`) but you can kind of see this as if the language were automatically creating an interface for you (`MyClassInterface x = new MyClass()`)

Comment: @missingno: that misses the point, the language element interface *may* be used *as one possible approach* for defining an ADT, but thats not obligatory. You can also create an ADT just by interpreting the public members of a class as beeing an interface (in the more general sense, not specifically the language element). And that leaves you still with the original question of the OP.

Comment: @missingno: the distinguishing difference between ADTs and objects is that there can only be one representation of an ADT in the system at any given time. You don't need interfaces to allow or different implementations because there can only ever be one. Objects allow multiple different representations of the same type to exist in the system, even the same object can change its representation over time. That's simply not possible with ADTs, because different instances of the same ADT can inspect each other's representation and thus must agree on a single one.

Comment: @missingno: Whereas with objects, two objects of the same type *cannot* inspect each other's representation, they can only use each other's public methods … and that's exactly the difference between classes and interfaces in a Java-like language: two instances of the same class can inspect each other's representation (even its `private` fields), whereas two instances of the same interface can't (since an interface can only contain `public` methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces are unrelated to Design Patterns. They are about Object-Orientation. In OO, the type of an object is defined by its behavior, i.e. by the protocol it speaks (its methods).

Classes in languages like Java and C#, however, also define representation (fields) in addition to behavior (methods). One of the basic tenets of OO is that objects *cannot* know the representation of other objects *even* of the *same* type. However, if you use classes as types, other objects of the same class *can* know the representation of other objects, even `private` fields. Therefore, using classes as types breaks OO. (Unfortunately, in both Java and C#, classes *are* types.)

The only way to do object-oriented programming in Java or C# is to use classes *only* as factories (i.e. *only* directly after `new`) and *never* as types (i.e. never as the type of a field, return type or parameter type of a method or type argument to a generic type, never cast to a class, never use it with `instanceof`). And as types, use *only* interfaces, not classes (and *certainly* not primitives in Java).

That's what interfaces do: they enable object-oriented programming in Java and C#, without them, OOP would simply be impossible in those languages.

Comment: Thanks Jorg. You answered my question. Interface are unrelated to Design Patterns.

Comment: There seems to be "your definition of OOP without any compromises", and "OOP as most of the rest of the world defines it". Interfaces have their place even without taking your IMHO single-edged point of view, thus I don't think this is a good answer to the OPs question (though you seem successfully made believe him so).

Comment: @DocBrown: this is not my definition of OOP. It's Alan Kay's definition, who after all invented the term. It's Benjamin Pierce's definition, who is one of the leading researchers on programming language theory. It's Willam R. Cook's definition, who is one of the leading researchers on data abstraction and OOP. Cook, in turn, extracted his definition by taking a look at what the common denominator between such diverse OO languages as Smalltalk, Java, C++, Eiffel, Oberon, CommonLisp, ECMAScript, Self etc. is, and he found that there is only one thing all those languages we call "OO" have in …

Comment: @DocBrown: … common: Procedural Data Abstraction. This is the *one* thing that distinguishes Objects from Abstract Data Types. In Java-like languages, Classes define ADTs, Interfaces define Objects. Since Design Patterns typically describe Objects, it is only natural that they use Interfaces.

Comment: You may not think of interfaces as being "related" to design patterns, but they certainly play a very important role.  They are an integral component of the Factory Pattern, for example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The Factory Pattern was invented in Smalltalk, which doesn't have interfaces. In fact, Design Patterns as a whole were first discovered in Smalltalk. The reason why the C# implementation of the Factory Pattern uses interfaces is because the Factory Pattern is an OO pattern and interfaces are the way to do OO in C#. (The same applies to Java, VB.NET and other similar languages.) If interfaces were integral, then the Factory Pattern couldn't exist in C++, Scala, Smalltalk, Ruby, Python, Newspeak, but certainly does. Interfaces are integral to OO in C#. Not to Design Patterns.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I hadn't heard that. I think we can agree that interfaces are central to the *implementation* of the Factory Pattern in C#, and that this is the way that a large percentage of people (who program in Java and C#) view the Factory Pattern.  On the whole, many software design patterns can be thought of as language workarounds, since some languages are expressive enough that those patterns are not even required to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Would one of you guys take a look at my question on interface-to-interface association? I feel like it is related to what is being discussed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095703/interface-to-interface-association-in-the-book-head-first-design-patterns

Answer (score 14):

Think of an interface like a Contract.  It's a way to say, "These classes should follow these set of rules."

Let's use an example and call it `IAnimal`.  We could say that the interface defines two methods `Run` and `Walk`. It's a way to say, "I MUST be able to call Run, Walk, etc. on classes which implement IAnimal."

Why is this useful?  You may want to build a function which relies on the fact that you must be able to call Run and Walk, for example, on the object.  You could have the following:

```
public void RunThenWalk(Monkey m) {
    m.Run();
    m.Walk();
}

public void RunThenWalk(Dog d) {
    d.Run();
    d.Walk();
}
```

... and repeat that for all objects which you know can run and walk.  However, with your IAnimal interface, you can define the function once as follows:

```
public void RunThenWalk(IAnimal a) {
    a.Run();
    a.Walk();
}
```

By programming against the interface, you are essentially trusting the classes to implement the intent of the interface.  So in our example, the thought is "I don't care *how* they Run and Walk, so long as they Run and Walk.  My RunThenWalk will be valid as long as they fulfill that agreement.  It functions perfectly well without knowing anything else about the class."

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the main purpose of interfaces as allowing code to be abstract as opposed to specific.  In a language with strong type safety, it allows you to treat multiple classes with similarities the same without needing to know which specific one of these types is being used.

For example, you could have an interface for People in which several child classes extend.  You could then have a method that deals in people, accepting any or all types of classes that implement People without any concern for what they are beyond that.  This is also provided by other forms of inheritance, but interfaces have the special restriction that they themselves can't have an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Larsenal](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/216858/75543) has given the best answer so far, but I'd like to expand on it to give a concrete example from working enterprise-level code (not in C#, but another ECMAScript-based language). In my code, I can treat Classes that are fundamentally different things as if they were the same from the viewpoint of the client code.

In my application, I have an IPaging Interface that defines functions like nextPage(), previousPage(), etc. This Interface is implemented by View Classes, but also by Controller Classes. What this allows me to do is bootstrap the application with a View that directly implements IPaging that gets passed to the Application's currentPaging variable. This View is already up and running while the Controllers are loaded with the data they need to proceed. This gets something interactive in front of users right away.

Once they're past that View, the Application's currentPaging variable is then given an instance of a Controller that implements IPaging. That Controller might then implement IPaging by calling those same functions on an IPaging View (that might again have IPaging Views inside it that allow nested, hierarchical navigation), or it might implement IPaging a different way, by swapping out pages of data to a View that has nothing to do with IPaging. The choices are literally limitless, and I can use the same Application framework with Views or Controllers that are customized to be slightly or very different based on the requirements we get. And our clients, like most clients, are nuts--so we have to be as flexible as possible.

I have never regretted using an Interface when perhaps there are only one or two implementations, but I have dearly regretted not using an Interface when I need an implementation that doesn't inherit from the same base Class and I didn't use an Interface. And once you have references to a specific Class spread all through your codebase and referenced from multiple projects, it's tough to put the genie back into the bottle.

One advantage of Interfaces that I get in the language I use (that I suspect you could also have in C#) is that I have the choice to load in implementations of the Interfaces I use at runtime from an external source. The loading Application doesn't need to compile in the Class definitions of the loaded implementations--it only needs the definition of the Interface to be able to cast to that Interface. Interfaces, by definition, have virtually no code in them.

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain it in terms of the article you linked to: the use of interfaces makes it possible to create unit tests for the `VehicleFacade`, to test that class in isolation. This can be accomplished by providing mock implementations of `IEngineController`, `ITransmissionController`, and so on, instead of using the real `EngineController`, `TransmissionController` etc.

Of course, those interfaces also allow to create different vehicles from different engine controllers, different transmission controller etc. and combine them freely. In real world scenarios, however, I expect the first use case (tests) to occur much more often then the second.

Answer (score 0):

The article you referenced is a terrible example for gaining an appreciation for what makes interfaces useful. It took me a really long time before I finally had that "aha" moment on what makes interfaces useful. The reason for it was because I thought of interfaces as glorified base classes whose name is twisted to sound action oriented, just like the article you referenced. It's no wonder I had this misperception because most articles talking about interfaces do the same thing.

The problem I had with "appreciating" interfaces was that they always seemed to morph into abstract base classes because it made the most sense. The alternative was to declare the interface, declare a derived(base) class of the interface that implemented many of the common methods that the concrete derived classes all shared. It didn't make sense to have 2 classes for most every interface just to provide the plumbing when 1 would do. So the interface inevitably simply switched to being an abstract base class.

My "aha" moment happened when I realized that even though the interface name was "action-oriented" it really was just a base class by a different name. Thus, IEngineController isn't really an interface, it is an EngineControllerBase Class. What I realized was that interfaces are most useful when they aren't tied into the derived class implementation, but instead describe distinct actions or capabilities in themselves.

Thus, IEngineController would be better (and provide for a far more illustrative article) if it was called IStartStoppable OR even have 2 separate interfaces. IStartable, IStoppable. At least for me, once I got past the definining interfaces as glorified abstract base classes stage then the value of interfaces start to shine.